# Bootstrap 3 modal backdrop is black

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap`s modal on my site and backdrop opacity is 1. I can change opacity by adding

```
.modal-backdrop.fade.in {
    opacity: 0.7!important;
}
```

in my .css file. But when I close modal, opacity changes to 1 and then closing - it's look ugly. I understood, that case in div, which appear in bottom of html document when modal is showing,

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in" style="opacity: 1;"></div>
```

but how to remove this div? And it's occure only on product page on other pages it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**!important** should override inline styles: https://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/

In your example you are missing a white space though.

```
    .modal-backdrop.fade.in {
         opacity: 0.7 !important;
    }
```

**Update**

I assume the modal-backdrop is without the `in` class on close

```
    .modal-backdrop.fade, .modal-backdrop.fade.in {
         opacity: 0.7 !important;
    }
```

Comment: It works without white space and problem in div, because when i close modal opacity goes from 0.7 to 1 and it looks like blink.

Comment: I assume the ```modal-backdrop``` is without the ```in``` class on close

Comment: How about a JS Fiddle example?

Comment: Solved problem by deleting some rows of my JQuery code, which is responsible for my own modal and it adds opacity 1 to this div, thank you for help!